# Integer to char - cast and print:

Tags: java, while-loop, itoa

I want to know the logic behind this programm and `(char`) cast.
How does it work and how it is printing all the letters, symbols and numbers

```
package ascii1
public class Ascii1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=1;
        while(i<122)
        {
            System.out.println((char)i+"\t");
            if (i%10==0)
                System.out.println("");
            i++;
        }

        } 
}
```

Its output is:

> //Blanks in the beginning...
>
> !  "
>
> ## $   %   &   '   (
>
> ) 
>   * 
>   +  ,
>   -  .   /   0   1   2
>
> 3  4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <
>
> =
>
> > ?   @   A   B   C   D   E   F
>
> G  H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P
>
> Q  R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
>
> [  \   ]   ^
>   _  `   a   b   c   d
>
> e  f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n
>
> o  p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x
>
> y  BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: what is your actual question on this code?

Comment: This is the most awefully formatted question I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ASCII` [representation](http://www.asciitable.com/mobile/), every char has a numerical value.

When you iterate, adding `+1` to the `i` variable, you get to numbers on the `ASCII` table representing some characters.

Finally, the `(char)` cast returns the above `ASCII` character.

Comment: Unicode characters with values under 32 are the so-called control characters, they don’t have a graphical representation, which is why you see nothing in the first several linesof output.